# Is there a groovy way of loading Jenkins builds?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

We have a kind of blue-green deployment which means we have 2 instances working at the same time and the difference between them is that one instance has few builds that don't exist on the other Jenkins.
We need now to rsync missing build folders from one Jenkins to other and cannot restart the second Jenkins that gets these builds.
So we would like to know a groovy way of loading competed builds from disk into Jenkins job history.
I saw `loadBuild` API and was happy for a moment but then I noticed it's protected.

```
protected R loadBuild(File dir)
               throws IOException

Loads an existing build record from disk.

Throws:
    IOException 

This is to get an idea what we want to achieve.
```

Comment: where you have found it's protected?

Comment: in the API documentation here: 
https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#loadBuild-java.io.File-